# Recode / rename data within a dataframe while grep is used to selected certain variables

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

In my dataframe I select only variables test3-test8

```
data[,grep('(test[3-8]+$)',names(data)),]
```

Now I want to replace `"1"` with `"2"`. According to `df[ df == "1" ] = "2"` I tried:

```
data[,grep('(test[3-8]+$)',names(data)),][ data[,grep('(test[3-8]+$)',names(data)),] == "1" ] = "2"
```

That didn't work.

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , grep("(^dv_beh_[0-9]+r)", names(data)),  : unused argument(s) ()

What is my mistake?

Comment: This code is tortuous. 1. Don't use `data` as a variable name, as it is a built-in function (it usually works fine, but can cause unexpected problems). 2. Create a variable to hold the results of the `grep` call - repeating such a long piece of code is bound to lead to errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eliminate the superfluous commas (which are specifying options to the data frame, but you list no options) and the error goes away:

```
dtf <- data.frame(test1=runif(10))
dtf <- cbind(dtf,dtf)
dtf <- cbind(dtf,dtf)
dtf[3,3] <- 1
names(dtf) <- paste("test",seq(ncol(dtf)),sep="")
names.sel <- grep('(test[3-8]+$)',names(dtf))
dtf[,names.sel][ dtf[,names.sel] == 1 ] <- 2
stopifnot(dtf[3,3]==2)
```

And to prove that that's the problem, I can reproduce the error with:

```
data[,names.sel,][ data[,names.sel] == 1 ,] <- 2
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , grep("(test[3-8]+$)", names(data)),  : 
  unused argument(s) ()
```

Comment: The third argument to "[data.frame<-" is _not_ a third dimension (there is no such incarnation of dataframes) but rather the optional arguments ( ,..., ) that are passed to other methods. I created a data.frame with numeric columns and two names that would match the pattern and still get an error with you modified code. (Also error with the OP's test data.frame.)

Comment: I was sloppy with my wording, sorry.  I assume he was thinking about it as a 3d matrix which is why he felt it necessary to put the extra commas in.  If he had wanted options, my assumption was that he would have listed a few.

Anyhow, I've made my solution more explicit above.  Please let me know if you can reproduce it, but it definitely works on my machine.

Comment: More specifically, the problem is with the comma in the first set of brackets. The reason is that while `[.data.frame` does take an optional argument (`drop`), `[<-.data.frame` does not.

Comment: @gsk3: Removed my objection. I do note that a comma in either of the [] invocations in the code above will throw an error.

Comment: @DWin: Thanks.  I had eliminated both commas but failed to write down that eliminating both were necessary to get rid of the error.  @Aniko: I believe that a comma to list options without any arguments specified in R is always bad syntax (unless it's for indexing, in which case the comma is serving a different purpose than delineating options).  E.g. `cat("HI","LOW","\n",)`

Comment: I agree that one should not put random commas in the code, even if the result happens to work. But I also figured out why you needed to remove both commas, while only removing the first worked for me: you have the second comma in the wrong place (as compared to the original code). Its simplified version should be `dtf[,names.sel,][ dtf[,names.sel,] == 1 ] <- 2`, and then removing only the first extra comma works.